# Targeting Frameworks suddenly gone missing from VS 2017

Tags: .net, windows, windows-10, visual-studio-2017

Something strange happened in my pc (I suspect windows update did it). Me and my team was working on a windows forms project (targeting .Net Framework 4.0 Client) from a past few months. Everything was fine until all of sudden, VS 2017 started telling me that .Net Framework 4.0 is not installed on system, here is a screenshot:

[image: .Net 4 gone missing]

We cannot upgrade target framework because we need to support Windows XP and .Net Framework 4 is the last one supported in xp.

Fortunately, in an another development machine .Net 4 is still available, here is a screenshot:

[image: .Net and other frameworks still available in vs 2017]

But, in my machine the case is this:

[image: .Net 4.0 went missing]

.Net 4.0 is even missing in this link from Microsoft:
https://www.microsoft.com/net/targeting

So, here is my question:

Is Microsoft is intentionally removing .Net 4.0 and other old frameworks from Windows 10, or is it just a bug in my machine?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Run visual studio setup to modify it, then from selection there is an option to target .net framework 4.0 select it & install.

I face same issue & solved by above step.